# adjusting json format send by extjs form

Tags: json, extjs

I have a question.

I need to send a json format to my backend service. It requires something i haven't managed to create. What i am sending with a form is this:

```
{
"jobs": {
    "name": "dsvs",
    "jobType": "CUSTOM",
    "description": "sdvsdv",
    "tasks": "14,15,16"
}
}
```

but what i need to send is

```
{
"jobs": {
    "name": "dsvs",
    "jobType": "CUSTOM",
    "description": "sdvsdv",
    "tasks": [14,15,16]
}
}
```

how can i do this?

This is my form handler:

```
handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    var formData = Ext.encode(form.getValues());
                    Ext.Ajax.request({

                        url: ND.url + 'dna/rjs/secure/service/rest/jobs.json',
                        method: 'POST',
                        waitTitle: 'Connecting',
                        waitMsg: 'Sending data...',
                        jsonData: {
                            jobs: form.getValues()
                        }


                            });


                    })
```

I hope anyone has an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't by "honest" ways.

You can, however, hack it into that one.

```
handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    var formData = Ext.encode(form.getValues());
                    formData.jobs.tasks = formData.jobs.tasks.split(',');
                    Ext.Ajax.request({

                        url: ND.url + 'dna/rjs/secure/service/rest/jobs.json',
                        method: 'POST',
                        waitTitle: 'Connecting',
                        waitMsg: 'Sending data...',
                        jsonData: {
                            jobs: formData
                        }
                   });
})
```

You don't use your `formData` in your example, despite having it, BTW.

That would result in:

```
{
"jobs": {
    "name": "dsvs",
    "jobType": "CUSTOM",
    "description": "sdvsdv",
    "tasks": ["14","15","16"]
}
}
```

If that is still not suitable, than you can further hack it by calling `parseInt` on each task value.

**EDIT**:

Added clarification.

Comment: Do i need to put this in the handler?

Comment: Thanks ZenMaster. This sounds like the solution for my problem. But i am doing something wrong i think. I keep getting: formData.jobs is undefined

Comment: The Ext.encode() step in there is not needed. Remove it and you get rid of the error.