# submit whole form to webservice

Tags: ext.net

I am using webservice.I wanna sumbit my form elements to the webservice,in your example ,it is possiable send parameterrs by one by.is there any way to submit whole form and parse it and reach serverside part.

```
 <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="XML WebMethod">
    <Listeners>
     <Click Handler="xmlService(#{txtName}.getValue());" />
      </Listeners>
   </ext:Button>

   var xmlService = function (name) {
            Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({
                url          : "XmlService.asmx/SayHello",
                cleanRequest : true,
                params       : {
                    name : name
                },
                success      : function (result) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Xml Message", Ext.DomQuery.selectValue("string", result, ""));
                }
            });
        };
```

or using  eventhandler

```
 <ext:Button runat="server" Text="[WebMethod]">
                    <DirectEvents>
                        <Click 
                            Url="TestService.asmx/SayHello1" 
                            Type="Load" 
                            Method="POST" 
                            CleanRequest="true">
                            <ExtraParams>
                                <ext:Parameter Name="name" Value="#{txtName}.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                            </ExtraParams>
                        </Click>
                    </DirectEvents>
                </ext:Button>
```

Comment: Make a JSON object from the form elements and send that to the server

Comment: is it ext.net approach? or generall approach

Comment: Its a general approach, i don't think there is an ext.net way, however as you know ext.net is based on extjs so check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340009/adjusting-json-format-send-by-extjs-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is the following form on the page.

```
<form runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server" />

    <ext:TextField ID="TextField2" runat="server" />
</form>
```

A DirectMethod call with a form submit.

```
Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({
    url    : "XmlService.asmx/Submit",
    formId : "form1"
});
```

A DirectEvent call with a form submit.

```
<DirectEvents>
    <Click Url="XmlService.asmx/Submit" />
</DirectEvents>
```

A Submit WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public object Submit(string TextField1, string TextField2)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you for response.Fist,what I understand from "A DirectEvent call with a form submit." is that,as a default DirectEvent  submit whole form and reach inside the webservice like this e.data.value.but the direct method,how can I reach form values inside webservice?

Comment: It should be done as for a common ASP.NET form submit to a WebService. You can iterate respective arguments in a WebMethod's signature. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Hi daniil,I have anaother question post here,can u take a look at this one.(I am sorry if it is not approipriate to ask this like that way,if so,I am sorry again).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669862/ext-net-loading-2-child-page-and-reach-from-one-child-to-another