# Ext.Net,loading 2 child page ,and reach from one child to another

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

My main.aspx

```
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" Theme="Gray" />
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="anaPanel" Title="OSO" Icon="Car">
        <TopBar>
            <ext:Toolbar runat="server" Layout="FitLayout">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Floating="false" Layout="HBoxLayout" ShowSeparator="false"
                        AnimCollapse="true" Cls="horizontal-menu">
                        <Defaults>
                            <ext:Parameter Name="MenuAlign" Value="tl-bl?" Mode="Value" />
                        </Defaults>
                        <Items>
                            <ext:MenuItem ID="MenuItem1" runat="server" Text="" Icon="Group">
                                <Menu>
                                    <ext:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:MenuItem Text="new card" Icon="GroupAdd">
                                           <DirectEvents>
                                           <Click OnEvent="AddNewCart_Click"></Click>
                                           </DirectEvents>

                                            </ext:MenuItem>
                                            ...............
                                            ...............
                                            </ext:Panel>

    </form>
```

My maninpage codebehind something like this.

```
 protected void AddNewCart_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {

        string path = "Pages/Kart.aspx";
        Window win = CreateWindows(MyWindow,Icon.Group,path,"new card", 420, 500);
        //  private Window CreateWindow(string Id, Icon ic, string path, string Title, int Heigh, int width){......};
       //I get the new Window and pass some values and turn it back.
        win.Render(this.Form);
        win.Show();
    }
```

inside Kart.aspx there is also a  button and when the clicked button , load second childpage just the same above code 
but changed path (lets say loading  B.aspx).I am doing this like that window.parent.App.direct.MethodName(). *[MethodName() descibed in the main.aspx] but I need to refresh a grid inside the Kart.aspx, when and new item from B.aspx,
*I have tried to reach Kart.aspx methon like this  window.parent.App.direct.MethodName() but seems doesnt work.it works only if it is described in the main.aspx codebehind.
 a friend told me that ,only way to do that is use javascript" like this

Code-Behind

```
X.Call("ReloadGrid");

 function ReloadGrid() {
            var grid = window.parent.Ext.getCmp('GridId');
            //grid reloading code
}
```

but I have no idea how I reload grid via this script.or are there anaother way to do this.thank you

my Kart.aspx ;

```
<ext:GridPanel runat="server" ID="grid1" Title="" Height="460"
                Flex="1" Scroll="Vertical">
                <Store>
                    <ext:Store ID="strKart" runat="server">
                        <Model>
                            <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" IDProperty="Id">
                                <Fields>
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="name" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="surname" />


                                </Fields>
                            </ext:Model>
                        </Model>
                        <Listeners>
                            <Exception Handler="Ext.Msg.alert('Products - Load failed', operation.getError());" />
                        </Listeners>
                    </ext:Store>
                </Store>
```

and code behind of it

```
 [DirectMethod]
        public void ReloadKart()
        {

            this.strKart.DataSource = cari_bll.GetAll();
            this.strKart.DataBind();
        }
```

**trying to  run ReloadKart () function from B.aspx which is clicked the button

Comment: so calling `window.parent.App.direct.ReloadKart()` makes an error?

Comment: yes as it is defined inside the Kart.aspx give error,however If I define it main page ,it works fine.as it is because both B.aspx and Kart.aspx render to form2 which insidethe  mainpage.aspx file.

Comment: calling the b.aspx from the Kart.aspx and render it to kart.aspx form, could be an option for me and can run the window.parent.App.direct.ReloadKart() inside Kart.aspx,but this time my B.aspx window shown inside the Kart.aspx window that I dont want.what I wand indepentdent windows inside the mainpage

Comment: I am sorry I am edit my question,İt shouldnt  Window win = CreateWindows(MyWindow,Icon.Group,path,"new card", 420, 500); somethink like this it should be   private Window CreateWindow(string Id, Icon ic, string path, string Title, int Heigh, int width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have 3 pages, the parent lets call it **Parent.aspx**, and the children **Kart.aspx**, and **b.aspx**

And you want to load the **grid** in **Kart.aspx** based on an **event** in **b.aspx**

Since you load the grid by calling the direct method

```
    [DirectMethod]
    public void ReloadKart()
    {    
        this.strKart.DataSource = cari_bll.GetAll();
        this.strKart.DataBind();
    }
```

its boils down to calling this method inside **Kart.aspx**

To achieve this you need to do the following:

1. Define a JavaScript method in **Kart.aspx** that calls the direct method `ReloadKart`, lets name it ReloadGrid

   ```
   function ReloadGrid()
   {
       App.direct.ReloadKart();
   }
   ```
2. Define a delegate to this method in **Parent.aspx**, lets call it `ReloadGridDelegate`, a method to call that delegate `CallKartReloadGrid`, and a method to set it `SetReloadGridDelegate`

   ```
   var ReloadGridDelegate;
   function CallKartReloadGrid()
   {
       ReloadGridDelegate();
   }
   function SetReloadGridDelegate(delegate)
   {
       ReloadGridDelegate = delegate;
   }
   ```
3. In **Kart.aspx** assign call the `SetReloadGridDelegate`

   ```
   window.parent.SetReloadGridDelegate(ReloadGrid);
   ```
4. Finally in **b.aspx** call the parent method

   ```
   window.parent.CallKartReloadGrid();
   ```

Comment: dear friend it works fine,u are so clever ,(it is clever way to use delegate with javascript)I respect you but how u leanr all those things can u share your source with me as well.thank you again

Comment: @user2460637 glad to be of help, well there is no one source, but Google is your best buddy, but if i were to name sources, then stackoverflow is a major source, along with codeproject, and the msdn forums, as for the ext framework, the forums and documentation of both ext.net and sencha.com are great sources, also one of the main sources of knowledge is experience, as you work on more projects and face more scenarios and try to solve new issues, you will learn many new things