# ExtJs:how can I create a window and load A.aspx page inside it

Tags: extjs

how can I create a window and load A.aspx to the inside of this window,but I wanna render window  to the form1 element.(Main.aspx).when I clcik the button run my script and load it.(I need to iframe  also)

something like this.

```
    function CretaeWindow(Id, title, path, width, height, icon) {
        var win = new Ext.Window({
            title: title
            , width: width
            , height: height
            , renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            , flex: "1"
            , closeAction: "destroy"
             , Layout: "Anchor"
             , iconCls: icon
            , modal: true
            , loader: {
                url: path,
                renderer: "frame",
                loadMask: {
                    showMask: true,
                    msg: "loading.."
                }
            }
        });
        win.show();

    }
```

however I at this time I coulnt reach the this window Id from codebehind :)

Comment: what you mean by 'I wanna render window to the form1 element.(Main.aspx)'

Comment: hello friend ,I found the answer,watching the fedler,converting code from ext.net to html :) .yes rendering the main.aspx.

Comment: if u remember my previous question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669862/ext-net-loading-2-child-page-and-reach-from-one-child-to-another),I render the window server side and send the client,and you told me that I can reach it via window.parent.Ext.getCmp('ComponenteID').close();but I change my mind and decide render windows on client side like the above on the main.aspx.but this time window.parent.Ext.getCmp('ComponenteID').close(); dosent work,I guess I render to wrong where windows.

Comment: you render it on main.aspx? then only do `Ext.getCmp('ComponenteID').close();`

Comment: nope I tryied it also but didnt work.

Comment: are you setting the window id correctly? it seem you are not assigning any id from the code above

Comment: upppssss,,,it is my  sillyyy,yes u are right :) thank you  so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seem you are not assigning any id to the window, this will make ext generate a random ID for it, assign an ID to be able to find it